# Should I use "a reduction" or "reductions"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Please help me to revise this sentence.
*This technique could provide a reduction of 3%, 2% and 1% for X, Y and Z, respectively.*
Should I use "*a reduction*" or "*reductions*"?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I would use "reductions", as you're referring to three separate reductions.

Answer (score 1):

Since by qualifying your statement with the adverb, 'respectively', you are relating the 3% reduction to X, the 2% reduction to Y, and the 1% reduction to Z, you should use '**a reduction**'. In other words, you are performing just one 'operation' on each variable.